# (Server Side) How to retrieve data from MarkLogic and paginate a few at a time

Tags: angularjs, typescript, pagination, marklogic

My aim is to retrieve the next 10 items from db each time I click the "next" button.

So instead of retrieving 100 records in a shot from db, which will likely lag the system, I only want to retrieve 10 at a time.

Below are a snippet of what I've done, not sure what else am I missing...

At resource.java

```
   @Autowired
   protected QueryManager queryManager;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/retrieveObjects/{page}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public ResponseEntity<Object[]> retrieveObjects(@PathVariable("page") String page){
      int pageNum = Integer.valueOf(page);
      int start = PAGE_SIZE_TEN * (pageNum - 1) + 1;
      SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle(); 
      queryDef.setDirectory(DIRECTORY);
      queryManager.setPageLength(PAGE_SIZE_TEN);
      queryManager.search(queryDef, resultsHandle, start);

      return new ResponseEntity<Object[]>(handleSearch(resultsHandle), HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

At component.ts

```
this.restclient.getjson('/api/retrieveObjects/'+page)
   .subscribe(objects => {
      for(let i=0; i<objects .length; i++){
      this.objects.push(objects[i]);
      } 
   });
```

At component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">
 <div (click)="gotoObject(object.id)">
     {{object.id}}
 </div>
</div>
<pagination-controls class="pagination" (pageChange)="p = $event;getPage($event)"></pagination-controls>
```

I have 100 records.

However, the result only shows 1 page of my first 10 records, the "next" button is disabled.
[image]

The expected result should show 1 page of first 10 records, clicking on "next" button will call the api/retrieveObjects/ to retrieve the next 10 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to implement the server-side pagination :

For that you have to pass one extra parameter `totalItems`

```
{
  "count": 100, // no of total records
  "data": [    // chunk of data (in your case chunk of 10 records)
    { /* item 1 */ },
    { /* item 2 */ },
    { /* item 3 */ },
    { /*   ...  */ },
    { /* item 10 */ }
  ]
}

<div *ngFor="let object of objects.data | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: objects.count }">
```

For more, please read :
http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/

Comment: So that means i'll still need to get the total number of items. Will that still slow down the processing time?

Comment: @Ronaldo, getting total records wont slow your processing, it might take few miliseconds not more.